# custom Slider without using the QML one?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm looking for sliders examples without using the QML one. Just by using rectabgle but i dont really know how to handle it?

The QML one dont have so much properties:

```
Slider {
        id: sliderHorizontal1
        x: 69
        y: 52
        activeFocusOnPress: true
        tickmarksEnabled: true
        minimumValue: 0
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: A very good [example](https://jryannel.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/slider-component/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer by using QML slider.

```
Slider {
        id: slider
        x: 56
        y: 53
        width: 450
        height: 30
        tickmarksEnabled: true
        activeFocusOnPress: true
        updateValueWhileDragging: true
        value: 10
        maximumValue: 30

        style: SliderStyle {
            handle: Rectangle {
                height: 40
                width: height
                radius: width/2
                color: "#fff"
            }

            groove: Rectangle {
                implicitHeight: 10
                implicitWidth: 100
                radius: height/2
                border.color: "#333"
                color: "#222"
                Rectangle {
                    height: parent.height
                    width: styleData.handlePosition
                    implicitHeight: 6
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    radius: height/2
                    color: "red"
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I can add modification inorder to match to my needs...
Thanks @Tarod

Comment: Mark your post as answer